# Circular image display on touch

Tags: java, android, image, android-layout, android-fragments

I have this image  in Android Fragment, which I want to display in parts when user touches the exact dimensions on the image:

Example: as user completes this gesture, this image keeps on loading

Is there any lib that I can use for this ? Any help will be appreciated.

[image]